# Alter main query to always list posts according to ACF number field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to do this for all places the main query appears?
I don't want to make any other modifications - simply just change the order of the main query.

Tried this without success:

```
function tas_album_query( $query ) {
    
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'tas_album_admin_acf_tas_album_order' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tas_album_query' );
```