# If all posts have exactly the same publication date/time, to the second, what order are they listed in the main query?

Tags: archives

In a default Wordpress setup with ten posts. If I manually update the publication date for all ten posts to be exactly the same date/time, then go to the blog page of the site to view them all, what order will they display in?

Normally they would be listed in chronological order with the most recent post appearing first. However, since they all have the same time, there is no way for Wordpress to do this.

Nevertheless, it still has to display them. So how does it determine which post to display first? Second? Third etc.

Comment: this doesn't make sense, the title is talking about all posts having the same date/time, but then the question text is asking about the order. Can you include examples, as well as the code in your question? The question can't be answered or understood in its current form. Use the edit link to improve your question and add more information

Comment: also could this be a direct result of the code in the question you asked yesterday? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/418257/alter-main-query-to-always-list-posts-according-to-acf-number-field

Comment: Edited to clarify. Assume it is a default install with no code modifications.

Comment: @Jules in short, it's implementation-dependant. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293373/how-order-by-ordered-if-they-are-same-value. The MySQL 8 ref manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) also stated that, "*the order is undefined for columns that are identical except for their case*". A 2nd column can be specified, e.g. `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC`, but WordPress doesn't do that by default.

Comment: @SallyCJ that's probably the best answer to this there is, can you post it as one?

Comment: @TomJNowell, I've just posted an answer, and sorry for the very late reply..

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's **implementation-dependant**. See:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293373/how-order-by-ordered-if-they-are-same-value

The MySQL 8 ref manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) also stated that:

> *On character type columns*, sorting—like all other comparison operations—is normally performed in a case-insensitive fashion. This
> means that the order is undefined for columns that are identical
> except for their case. You can *force a case-sensitive sort* for a
> column by using `BINARY` like so: `ORDER BY BINARY col_name`.

A second column can be specified, e.g. `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC`, but WordPress doesn't do that by default.

I made a [demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aU713xcxjuXEjycB9xeVf9/0) which demonstrates the above "*normally performed in a case-insensitive fashion*" and the "2nd column" thing.

- At the time of writing, DB Fiddle seemed to be using the PK (primary key) column to sort columns that are identical (see Query #1 in [another demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aU713xcxjuXEjycB9xeVf9/1)). My test site also seemed to be doing the same (), see [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H81j5.png) and [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0HLf.png).

So, that *might* also be the case with your RDBMS/hosting, but you would need to consult your hosting support regarding that.